# Make one combobox dictate the options available in the second combobox

Tags: ms-access, controls

Salutations.

TL;DR - How do I set combobox2 to populate different tables based on combobox1?
(Access365 - version 2302)

•The Background
I'm relatively new to MS Access (Access365). I preface with this, because my question most likely has a painfully obvious answer to you, so I apologize in advance.

I have been tasked by a project specialist to figure out a way for a department to go paperless (because I'm the only one in our lab that can tell a USB and PS/2 port apart, apparently).

The idea is one database that has many tables in it, to limit redundancy. A QC log, a table for each of 13 instruments to manage all the reagents (lots and expiration dates), master inventory to name a few. The hope is from a single database, with a few different user forms as front-ends, the Sup and Lead can review all data without digging through *literally thousands* of papers.

I decided to start with the QC Log form, because that is what will be used most frequently by us front-line workers.

•The Issue
What I'm currently trying to do on the QC form involves two combo boxes: one to select the instrument to report the QC failure, and one to select which reagent failed. What I would like to happen is the combobox for the instrument to determine what table the reagent combobox references, and then be able to submit those selections into the QCLog table. I've managed to make a "submit" button on a different form for a different project to work, but this is beyond my google-fu. My thought was something like:

```
Private Sub instrument_AfterUpdate()

If Me.Instrument.Value = "DxC 1" then
   Set Me.Reagent As Table.dxc1.reagents     'the table being DxC1, and the column being the reagents column
      ElseIf Me.Instrument.Value = dxc2 then(...)(etc.)
End If

End sub
```

But I can't find the correct syntax for defining table objects (if it even exists). I've seen other posts suggesting subforms on forms to access different tables, but to build subforms for one control seems... inefficient. What suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 1):

First, I think your data model could be tweaked. There is no need to have a table for each for reagents. One table would be enough with an additional field for the instrument.
In this way you have your combobox with the instrument selection and in the AfterUpdate event wou write this code:

```
Me!cbo_Reagents.RowSource = "SELECT Reagentname FROM tbl_Reagents WHERE InstrumentID= " & Me!Instrument
```

Me!Instrument is your instrument combobox, cbo_Reagents is the combobox for the reagents.

If you want to stick with your separate tables of reagents for each instrument, then change the code:

```
Select Case Me.Instrument.Value
Case "DxC 1"
   Me!cbo_Reagents.RowSource = "SELECT Reagentname FROM tbl_Reagents_DxC1"
Case "DxC 2"
   Me!cbo_Reagents.RowSource = "SELECT Reagentname FROM tbl_Reagents_DxC2"
' fill in more variations here
End Select
```

Adapt the table names and fields you want to show.

Comment: Okay, the second example worked! Thanks! It's not that *I* want the database to have dozens of tables, but unfortunately the people in charge are specifying *they* think it's better that way. Regardless, thank you! I'm trying to upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation...